# twisted location header redirect

Tags: python, redirect, http-headers, location, twisted

From the `render_GET` method of a `Resource` in `twisted`, is it possible to redirect to a different url entirely (hosted elsewhere)

`request.redirect(url)` doesn't appear to do anything, and neither does `twisted.web.util.Redirect`

The equivalent in php would be,

```
header('location:'.$url);
```

### EDIT

this is the code I'm running

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Simple(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        request.redirect("www.google.com")
        request.finish()

site = server.Site(Simple())
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Please post *complete* examples. Both of the methods you reference work just fine, so clearly you're mis-using them somehow, but we can't tell how because you haven't included any code.

Comment: @Glyph I've added the code to the question. I had tried several things, and wasn't sure any of them were correct. I thought the answer would be simple and wouldn't require the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked it out in the end with help from the other poster, with `request.finish()`, the redirect including `http://` and returning `NOT_DONE_YET`

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Simple(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        request.redirect("http://www.google.com")
        request.finish()
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET

site = server.Site(Simple())
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: You don't need to call request.finish() and return server.NOT_DONE_YET.  You can just return "" instead.

Comment: **One observation**: If you use this (finish()+NOT_DONE_YET) you'll get problems with upstream proxy servers. **nginx** was returning me a "502 Bad Gateway". I usually use return "", which has no problems with nginx. So this doesn't seem to be the correct answer. It also is a bit strange why you would want to set the server into a NOT_DONE_YET state, since the redirect is a full reply that can cleanly close the channel. AFAIK you have to deal with NOT_DONE_YET states at some time, manually, by calling finish() and returning the answer.

Answer (score 3):

[`Location` header requires absolute url](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30) e.g., `http://example.com`.

[302 Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.3) response code says that we SHOULD provide a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI. `redirectTo()` does exactly that:

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.web.util import redirectTo
from twisted.internet import reactor

class HelloResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return redirectTo('http://example.com', request)

reactor.listenTCP(8080, server.Site(HelloResource()))
reactor.run()
```

Or using `Redirect`:

```
from twisted.web import server
from twisted.web.util import Redirect
from twisted.internet import reactor

reactor.listenTCP(8080, server.Site(Redirect("http://example.com")))
reactor.run()
```

Or just using `web` twistd plugin, put in `redirect.rpy` file:

```
from twisted.web.util import Redirect

resource = Redirect("http://example.com")
```

run:

```
$ twistd -n web --port tcp:8080:localhost --resource-script redirect.rpy
```

Just for a demonstration, here's how an implementation of [`redirectTo()`](https://github.com/powdahound/twisted/blob/93389d012a77dae35ddc6d99b014064ffe8734b8/twisted/web/util.py#L29) could look like:

```
def redirect_to(url, request):
    request.setResponseCode(302) # Found
    request.setHeader("Location", url)
    request.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
    return """put html with a link to %(url)s here""" % dict(url=url) # body
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to redirect by using `request.redirect(url)` and then calling `request.finish()`.  Please verify that you are calling `request.finish()`.

Comment: I get `exceptions.RuntimeError: Request.write called on a request after Request.finish was called.` if I call finish

Comment: The `.redirect` method appears to only redirect locally anyway: `http://localhost:8080/www.google.com` whereas I want to go to `www.google.com`

Comment: Why are you calling `request.write()` after a `request.redirect()` and `request.finish()`?  All content on a response will be ignored after a redirect is processed in the header.

Comment: I didn't, something must do after the method returns

Comment: Okay, I referred to the documentation at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.web.resource.Resource.html#render .  It looks like this method is expected to return a string.  You might be able to avoid that expectation by putting `return twisted.web.server.NOT_DONE_YET` as per the docs.  However, be aware that this seems to be a little too complex for this extremely simplified webserver framework.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) the webserver does a whole lot more, but this is just a part of it :P